# Check if xml node has attribute

Tags: c#, xml, linq-to-xml

I have an XML file which is generated from a windows application like below "Repport.xml":

```
<ArrayOfAutoReportXML>  
    <AutoReportXML ReportName="Report1" ReportID="1" />
    <AutoReportXML ReportName="Report2" ReportID="2" />
    <AutoReportXML ReportName="Report3" ReportID="3" />
    <AutoReportXML ReportName="Report4" ReportID="4" />
    <AutoReportXML ReportName="Report5" ReportID="5" />
</ArrayOfAutoReportXML>
```

I am trying to check if ReportName already exists and i am trying below code to do that:

```
using (FileStream fs = new FileStream("Repport.xml", FileMode.Open, FileAccess.ReadWrite, FileShare.ReadWrite))
{
    XDocument doc = XDocument.Load(fs);

    string attrReportname = (string) doc.Elements("AutoReportXML")
        .Where(ox => ox.Attribute("ReportName").Value.ToString() == ReportName)
        .FirstOrDefault();
}
```

And `attrReportName` is `null`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue is that `Elements` will only find the immediate child Elements from the current context.  The only element returned by `doc.Elements()` would be `ArrayOfAutoReportXML`.

What you need is `Descendants`, which traverse *all* elements in the document.

To check if a report exists based on that attribute:

```
var reportExists = doc
    .Descendants("AutoReportXML")
    .Attributes("ReportName")
    .Any(x => x.Value == "Report1");
```

If you needed to check using more than one attribute:

```
var reportExists = doc
    .Descendants("AutoReportXML")
    .Any(x => (string)x.Attribute("ReportName") == "Report1" && 
              (int)x.Attribute("ReportID") == 1);
```

See [this fiddle](https://dotnetfiddle.net/SbmMzB) for a working demo.

Comment: how to check reportname and reportid more than one attribute.

Comment: @Tan I've added a second example

Comment: thank you sir, it has become big headache for me for 20 minutes..thank you